# how to pass context(ApplicationContext) as an argument to logBefore Method(Method of Aspect)?

Tags: aop, aspectj, eager-loading, pointcut, cross-cutting-concerns

I want to implement an aspect to avoid lazy Loading problems . 
so how to pass context(Application Context) as an argument for logBefore  Method?
What is the signature pointcut defines the method above(the place to which I make "???"), knowing that this method (logBefore) will be execute before all the methods that have "Set"
  as a result type and "slm.aoa.buisiness.facade" as package

```
 @Aspect
      public class EagerLoading {


    @Before("execution(???)")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) context.getBean("sessionFactory");
          Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, true);
          TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactory, new SessionHolder(session));
    }
```

and Thanks for your Help .

Comment: Your question has not got any attention so far, maybe because your way of expressing your concern is somewhat fuzzy. I guess I have an idea about what you want to know/do anyway, so if your problem is not obsolete yet, please extend your question by showing some of the method signatures you want to match. Is 'context' part of the parameter list? If so, you probably want to use an around() advice. I am going to answer when I know more from you.